# how can signals interrupt a system call

Tags: linux, signals, ipc

I was reading an article and I read the following: **Suppose we want to execute an external command and wait until it exits. We don't want to wait forever, we want to set some timeout after which we will kill the child process. How to do this? To run a command we use fork(2) and execve(2). To wait for a specific process to exit we can use the waitpid(2) function, but it has no timeout parameter. We can also create a loop in which we call sleep(3) with the timeout as an argument and use the fact that sleep(3) will be interrupted by the SIGCHLD signal. This solution will work... almost. It would contain a race condition: if the process exits immediately, before we call sleep(3) we will wait until the timeout expires. It's a race similar to the one described previously.** How is the system call interrupted? does the child send the signal to the parent process or the the system call sleep(3)? I don't get how the system call stop execution and passes to the parent process, is the system call like another process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the system call interrupted? does the child send the signal to the parent process or the the system call sleep(3)?

When the child process executes the system call **exit**(2), the kernel function [`do_exit()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/exit.c?v=4.6#L652), from there [`exit_notify()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/exit.c?v=4.6#L584) and from there [`do_notify_parent()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/signal.c?v=4.6#L1565) is called, which sends `SIGCHLD` to the parent and calls `__wake_up_parent()`.

> I don't get how the system call stop execution and passes to the
>   parent process, is the system call like another process?

The system call underlying `sleep()` puts the calling process in the state TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE - see e. g. [Sleeping in the Kernel](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144). After that, the process is simply not scheduled until woken up as by `__wake_up_parent()` above or the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You could fork a child using gnu **popen** Ref [gnu libc Pipe to a Subprocess](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html) .

This might help if you wanted to stop the **child** from being able to **reset** the **alarm**.

And then use

> The **alarm** and **setitimer** functions provide a mechanism for a process to interrupt itself in the future. They do this by setting a timer; when the timer expires, the process receives a signal.

NB You would call the above **before** execve

> Portability Note: The **setitimer** and **getitimer** functions are derived from BSD Unix, while the **alarm** function **is specified by the POSIX.1** standard. **setitimer** is more powerful than **alarm**, but **alarm is more widely used**.

Ref [libc Setting Alarm](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-an-Alarm.html)

You could also use **timeout** Ref [man timeout part of coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)

All the best